# How can I mock service in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler @ControllerAdvice

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, spring-mvc-test

I have `Controller`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

  private final UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  public UserController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService= userService;
  }

  @PostMapping(value = "/login")
  public UserDto login(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
    return userService.getUserWithAuth(user);
  }
}
```

I have `ControllerAdvice`:

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  private final ErrorMessagesService errorMessagesService;

  @Autowired
  public ExceptionHandlerAdvice(ErrorMessagesService errorMessagesService) {
    this.errorMessagesService = errorMessagesService;
  }


  @ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
  protected ResponseEntity<RestResponse<RestResponse.RestError>> handleSomeException(SomeException e) {
    ErrorMessage messages = errorMessagesService.findByCode(e.getCode());
    RestResponse.RestError restError = new RestResponse.RestError(e.getCode(), formatErrorMessage(messages));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new RestResponse<>(restError, null));
  }
}
```

And I write UnitTest for My controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean(name = "mockUserService")
  private UserService userService;

  private UserDto userDtoResponse;
  private UserDto userDtoRequest;

  @Before
  public void init() {

    cashierDtoRequest = new UserDto();
    userDtoRequest.setLogin("Test");
    userDtoRequest.setPassword("Test");

    userDtoResponse= new UserDto();
    userDtoResponse.setLogin("Test");
    userDtoResponse.setPassword("Test");
    userDtoResponse.setAuthToken("123");

    when(userService.getUserWithAuth(userDtoRequest)).thenReturn(userDtoResponse);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/user/login")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login").value(userDtoResponse.getLogin()))
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$.authToken").value(userDtoResponse.getAuthToken())));
  }
```

But when I start test I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'mypackeg.ErrorMessagesService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: Have you tried `@MockBean ErrorMessagesService errorMessagesService` in your test class?

Comment: @ Sam Brannen yes I tried and now I get exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
if I remove @EnableJpaRepositories test work

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude creating of bean in `@WebMvcTest` by using option of annotation

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class,
 excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = ExceptionHandlerAdvice.class ))
```